# Installing Plone on Centos fails: Unable to find libssl or openssl/ssl.h

Tags: centos, openssl, plone

My dedicated Server has CentOS 5.5. I tried to install Plone, so I basically did:

```
wget launchpad.net/plone/4.0/4.0.2/+download/Plone-4.0.2-UnifiedInstaller.tgz
tar xzf Plone-4.0.2-UnifiedInstaller.tgz
cd Plone-4.0.2-UnifiedInstaller
./install.sh zeo
```

I ran into the following error:

```
Unable to find libssl or openssl/ssl.h.
If you wish to build without SSL support, run install.sh again with
--without-ssl flag.
Otherwise, install your platform's openssl-dev libraries and headers
and try again.
```

After this error I successfully installed openssl:

```
yum install openssl
```

And i tried to install Plone again. But I keep getting the error: 
"Unable to find libssl or openssl/ssl.h". Anybody an idea what I'missing?

Answer (score 2):

Development files for `<package>` are usually in `<package>-devel`. Install `openssl-devel`.

Comment: I just found the correct answer,too. But very quick reply, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my error. I had to not only download openssl but also openssl-devel like so:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```